# Total number members in a group

Tags: php

I have an array comming like this and I want its sum as described below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [group] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [group] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [group] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [group] => 3
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [group] => 3
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [group] => 3
        )

)
```

I want result to show like this:

> Group 1 has 1 members. Group 2 has 2 members. Group 3 has 3 members.

Comment: I was try this way:
Get List of all Groups first then foreach group find all members in that group.
 But this seems more complicated way... maybe there is a easy way to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute below code that will help you.

```
$arr_ids    =   array(array('id'=>10,'group'=> '1'),
                      array('id'=>20,'group'=> '1'),
                      array('id'=>30,'group'=> '2'),
                      array('id'=>40,'group'=> '3'),
                      array('id'=>50,'group'=> '3'),
                      array('id'=>60,'group'=> '3'),
                      array('id'=>70,'group'=> '4'),
                );

foreach($arr_ids as $ids)
{
    $arr_groups[]   = $ids['group'];
}   
$count_arr  =   array_count_values($arr_groups);
print"<pre>"; 
print_r($arr_groups);
print_r($count_arr);

foreach($count_arr as $group=>$count)
{
    echo "Group ".$group." = ".$count."<br>";
}
print"</pre>";
```